# Is it possible to interact with a Linux Command line interface (CLI) through a Graphical user interface (GUI)?

Tags: java, c++, linux, qt

I am quite a beginner, any advice is much appreciated.

I have a linux application `OpenBTS` used to simulate and run a GSM network on a software defined radio device e.g USRP.

I want to build an application that interfaces with the OpenBTS command line on Linux. I want to give the user an easier way to configure and to display the current configurations of the application. The user would have an interface in which he could play with the configurations without the need to use the  terminal.

I don't know if this is possible ?
Is it possible to interact with a Linux CLI through a GUI ? If yes what is the most efficient programming language, coding technique or approach to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since this is tagged `qt` you could take  a look at [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Comment: it's possible. it's possible through a GUI. Most efficient programming language to do that is c++ as you've tagged. Use Qt as GUI library because it's the easiest way to have GUI on Linux with c++ and as @G.M. said, have a look at QProcess.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a config file using your GUI and then use [standard in](http://www.linfo.org/standard_input.html) to get the configuration into OpenBts. When launching OpenBts with the configuration file config.txt you could simply run it as follows.

> ./OpenBts < config.txt

You could also do this from you GUI by launching OpenBts in a process from your GUI application in a similar fashion, however this requires a [fork()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [exec()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can take inputs from user through GUI then run appropriate openBTS commands using system()/popen(). Based on the return values of system()/popen(), can provide status of the operation back to the user.